# Visio reverse engineering MS Access - missing driver

Tags: database, ms-access, visio

I am trying to use the "reverse engineering" feature of Visio to document an existing MS Access database.

I have done that in the past with decent results but I am having an issue at the moment.

Visio doesn’t propose me the MS Access driver - I only have these

[Driver options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G47Fp.png)

(Generic ODBC works but is fairly limited in terms of information retrieved).

I am trying to “install” / activate the Access driver but to no avail.

[Install options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdlbC.jpg)

What am I doing wrong ?

This is Microsoft® Visio® Plan 2 MSO (Version 2206 Build 16.0.15330.20260) 64-bit

Comment: Article [Database Reverse Engineering for Visio Plan 2](https://www.orbussoftware.com/resources/blog/article/DATABASE-REVERSE-ENGINEERING-FOR-VISIO-PRO) by [David J Parker](https://mvp.microsoft.com/en-us/PublicProfile/21090). It describes the main limitations…

Answer (score 2):

If you running office x64 version, then you need to install Access x64, or at the very least install the x64 bit version of the access data engine.

So, since now most office versions default to x64 bits, then you need a x64 bit driver for Access.

You can download the drivers here - they should work:

Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920

Make sure you choose + install the x64 bit version if  you are in fact running office/Visio x64.

Do keep in mind while Visio can pull and diagram the database, the options to create a database or forward engineer a database are long gone and removed from Visio. So changes made to that diagram and the Access schema in that diagram can't be sent back to Access, or any other database.

Comment: Thanks for your input.

I am using Office 365 E5 so I would have though Access would be fully available (it is working fine). Still on the off-chance that it would help I have installed the Access x64 engine - to no avail (no change whatsover).

The strange thing is that I am only offered 

ODBC Generic
Microsoft SQL
Oracle server

As valid “Visio driver” (whatever these actually are). If I go to “setup” I am offered an Access Driver but it does not show up afterwards (see above screenshots).

Not sure what is going on here

Comment: there is some suggesting that they don' support ms-access anymore. (can't imagine why - but the articles suggest that Access don't work with Visio anymore. I not used Visio in some time - but I do have Visio 2010 installed on my computer - but that's of little help. So, not 100% sure, but links and recent articles suggest that ms-access is not supported anymore.